# How to wire classes and objects in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Have SpringBoot Java app with different classes. I am not able to inject the dependencies and initialize/access the object of one class into another . Have seen the spring doc and used the annotations (@component,@Autowired etc. ), still there is an issue.

following are the classes.

**Main Class ()**

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CostmanagementApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CostmanagementApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller class**

```
package com.test;

import javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


@Component
@Controller
public class HighChartsController {
    
    @Autowired
    private RequestToken rt;
    
    @GetMapping("/costdata")
    public static String customerForm(Model model) {

    //here not able to access the getToken() method 
                
        model.addAttribute("costdata", new CostDataModel());        
        return "costdata";
    }

}
```

**RequestToken Class**

```
   package com.test;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URI;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import java.net.http.HttpClient;
    import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
    import java.net.http.HttpRequest.BodyPublishers;
    import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
    import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.util.Base64;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    @Component
    public class RequestToken {
        
    
        public String getToken() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            // code to get the token 
        return token;
}
}
```

now eventhough , I have all annotation in place , not getting why the `getToken()` method is not accessible  in controller class using rt object. please suggest

Comment: what exactly do you mean by not able to access getToken() method?

Comment: you have to use the rt field to access to the getToken method. Like in classical java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's go in order.

First of all, all the annotations `@Service`, `@Controller` and `@Repository` are specifications from `@Component`, so you don't need to specify `@Component` and `@Controller` in your `HighChartsController`.

Actually, if you check what the annotation `@Controller` definition is, you'll find this:

```
@Component
public @interface Controller {
  ...
}
```

Secondly, I don't really know what do you mean with that you aren't able to access the `getToken()` method, but as you wrote it seems you tried to access to that method as an `static` method.

You're injecting the object, so you use the methods of the objects like in plain Java: `rt.getToken()`. The only difference is that the `RequestToken` object will be already initialized at the moment you call it.

```java
package com.test;

import javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HighChartsController {
    
    @Autowired
    private RequestToken rt;
    
    @GetMapping("/costdata")
    public static String customerForm(Model model) {

        String token = rt.getToken(); 

        ...
                
        model.addAttribute("costdata", new CostDataModel());        
        return "costdata";
    }

}
```